# Java 8: merging two Lists containing objects by Id

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have 2 Lists:

```
// old list
List<Employee> oldList = new ArrayList<>();
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setPersonalNumber("123");
emp1.setName("old_name1");
emp1.setStatus(Status.OLD);

Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setPersonalNumber("456");
emp2.setName("old_name2");
emp2.setStatus(Status.OLD);

oldList.add(emp1);
oldList.add(emp2);

// new list
List<Employee> newList = new ArrayList<>();
Employee newEmp1 = new Employee();
newEmp1.setPersonalNumber("123");
newEmp1.setName("new_name1");
newEmp1.setStatus(Status.NEW);

Employee newEmp2 = new Employee();
newEmp2.setPersonalNumber("456");
newEmp2.setName("new_name2");
newEmp2.setStatus(Status.NEW);

newList.add(newEmp1);
newList.add(newEmp2);
```

Does anyone know how can I merge those 2 Lists to one List containing all the employees from both lists grouped by "PersonalNumber" and keeping the order of the elemets in newList? 
**newList comes from the Database with a predefined sorting, and I need to keep it that way, so I can't sort it again on the Java side**

Result should be:

```
[
    {"123", "new_name1", NEW},
    {"123", "old_name1", OLD},
    {"456", "new_name2", NEW},
    {"456", "old_name1", OLD},
]
```

I have the guarantee that both lists have the same size and contain employees with the same personalNumbers. I just want to "inject" each old employee under the new employee with the same personalNumber

Comment: what do you mean with "keeping the order of the elemets in newList"? are they sorted by `personalNumber`? you can create an new list, add all elements of `oldList` and `newList` and then sort this aggregated list in the same way you sorted `newList`.

Comment: newList comes from the Database with a predefined sorting, and i need to keep it that way

Comment: something like this could help you: Stream.of(listA, listB).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collections to sort should work for this.

```
newList.addAll(oldList);
Collections.sort(newList, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getPersonalNumber) );
```

The key is that, "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort."

Since cannot sort the new list, I take that to mean you don't know the order of the new list. You can do it the ol' N^2 method.

```
for(int i = 0; i<newList.size(); i+=2){
    String newNum = newList.get(i).getPersonalNumber();
    Employee old = oldList.stream().filter(
          emp->newNum.equals(
              emp.getPersonalNumber()
          )
        ).findFirst().orElse(null);
    newList.add(i+1, old);
    oldList.remove(old); //not nescessary?
}
```

Comment: newList comes from the Database with a predefined sorting, and I need to keep it that way, so I can't sort it again on the Java side

Comment: @Cambiasso so you don't want to sort the newlist at all, not even by personalNumber? Do you have any guarantees about the ordering of newlist? Why do you even want a List as a result?

Comment: @Cambiasso I am not clear why this answer doesn't work. Is the problem that the new list gets sorted? So you just need to make a copy of the newList? Why do you want a list at all? What is the point of grouping these values in a list?

Comment: I have the guarantee that both lists have the same size and contain employees with the same personalNumbers. I just want to "inject" each old employee under the new employee with the same personalNumber

Comment: @Cambiasso I updated it to include an N^2 algorithm. It wouldn't be too bad if you sort the old list to have the same ordering though.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this: As you mentioned that both lists have the same *PersonalNumber* so you can group by using this property. To ensure order based on the `personalNumber`, I've used `LinkedHashMap`.

```
Stream.concat(newList.stream(), oldList.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getPersonalNumber,
                    LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
            .values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:** *The result of `stream#concat` is ordered if both of the input streams are ordered.*

Comment: Seems complicity isn't your concern!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
// Sort oldList on personalNumber for faster access when retrieving the records
// with same personalNumber
oldList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getPersonalNumber));

List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();

for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) {
    // Get an employee, `e` from `newList` and add to `result`
    Employee e = newList.get(i);
    result.add(e);

    // Add elements from `newList` to `result` until a different `personalNumber`
    // occurs
    while (i < newList.size() - 1 && e.getPersonalNumber().equals(newList.get(i + 1).getPersonalNumber())) {
        result.add(newList.get(++i));
    }

    // Iterate `oldList` to find an employee with the `personalNumber` equal to that
    // of `e`
    int j;
    boolean found = false;
    for (j = 0; j < oldList.size(); j++) {
        if (oldList.get(j).getPersonalNumber().equals(e.getPersonalNumber())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If `oldList` has an employee with the `personalNumber` equal to that of `e` ,
    // add elements from `oldList` to `result` until a different `personalNumber`
    // occurs. Note that `oldList` has already been sorted.
    if (found) {
        result.add(oldList.get(j));
        while (j < oldList.size() - 1 && oldList.get(++j).getPersonalNumber().equals(e.getPersonalNumber())) {
            result.add(oldList.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

enum Status {
    OLD, NEW;
}

class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String personalNumber;
    private Status status;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(String name, String personalNumber, Status status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPersonalNumber() {
        return personalNumber;
    }

    public void setPersonalNumber(String personalNumber) {
        this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return personalNumber + ", " + name + ", " + status;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // old list
        List<Employee> oldList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setPersonalNumber("123");
        emp1.setName("old_name1");
        emp1.setStatus(Status.OLD);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setPersonalNumber("456");
        emp2.setName("old_name2");
        emp2.setStatus(Status.OLD);

        oldList.add(emp1);
        oldList.add(emp2);

        // new list
        List<Employee> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee newEmp1 = new Employee();
        newEmp1.setPersonalNumber("123");
        newEmp1.setName("new_name1");
        newEmp1.setStatus(Status.NEW);

        Employee newEmp2 = new Employee();
        newEmp2.setPersonalNumber("456");
        newEmp2.setName("new_name2");
        newEmp2.setStatus(Status.NEW);

        newList.add(newEmp1);
        newList.add(newEmp2);

        // Sort oldList on personalNumber for faster access when retrieving the records
        // with same personalNumber
        oldList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getPersonalNumber));

        List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) {
            // Get an employee, `e` from `newList` and add to `result`
            Employee e = newList.get(i);
            result.add(e);

            // Add elements from `newList` to `result` until a different `personalNumber`
            // occurs
            while (i < newList.size() - 1 && e.getPersonalNumber().equals(newList.get(i + 1).getPersonalNumber())) {
                result.add(newList.get(++i));
            }

            // Iterate `oldList` to find an employee with the `personalNumber` equal to that
            // of `e`
            int j;
            boolean found = false;
            for (j = 0; j < oldList.size(); j++) {
                if (oldList.get(j).getPersonalNumber().equals(e.getPersonalNumber())) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If `oldList` has an employee with the `personalNumber` equal to that of `e` ,
            // add elements from `oldList` to `result` until a different `personalNumber`
            // occurs. Note that `oldList` has already been sorted.
            if (found) {
                result.add(oldList.get(j));
                while (j < oldList.size() - 1 && oldList.get(++j).getPersonalNumber().equals(e.getPersonalNumber())) {
                    result.add(oldList.get(j));
                }
            }
        }

        // Display the result
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123, new_name1, NEW
123, old_name1, OLD
456, new_name2, NEW
456, old_name2, OLD
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this will not solve my problem properly, because as I mentioned the newList comes already sorted from the db (sort by personalNumber, or by name or by other attributes), and I have to keep that order and inject the old employees under their corresponding new employees (with the same personalNumber) no matter the sorting

Comment: @Cambiasso - I've updated the answer as per your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.

Comment: @Cambiasso - Did you try this solution? Please do not take it otherwise i.e. I'm not asking you to accept/upvote it if it works. You can use it as a backup solution. In fact, when I wrote it, I didn't realize that you needed a solution based on Java `Stream` and lambda as your question doesn't mention it clearly. However, when I read your question again, I saw that you have mentioned `Java 8` but it still doesn't convey clearly that you needed a solution based on Java `Stream` and lambda. Wish you success!

Comment: I don't have time to benchmark this, but can see that while not as elegant as the streaming solutions, it shows a lot of effort towards making sure it will run efficiently on large lists (without affecting the order of `newList`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @anjsimmo for reviewing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with Java streams and InsStream

```
private List<Employee> mergeLists(List<Employee> oldList, List<Employee> newList) {
    return IntStream.range(0, oldList.size())
            .mapToObj(index -> Arrays.asList(newList.get(index), oldList.get(index)))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This approach is possible because of

> I have the guarantee that both lists have the same size and contain employees with the same personalNumbers.

Comment: This solution works when both lists are in same order.